# Issue with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

Im a beginner and I am facing this issue. I know this is simple, but am not able to debug this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="process.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The PHP processing it is as follows. But I always get "NOT VALID" even though the credentials are right.

```
<?php

$name= $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($name=="admin"){
     if($password=="admin123")
         echo "VALID";
}
else
     echo "NOT VALID";
?>
```

Comment: It does work as expected, only thing to note here is to use `&&` to satisfy another condition that, if `name` is correct, but `password` is wrong, it displays none

Comment: So it did work, you just entered the wrong value. The question is not really relevant right? :)

Comment: No, even with both of them right, it goes to "else"

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&` Condition rather then two if condition. Try this one.

Use Logical Operators. Check more operators Demo  **[Logical Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)**

```
<?php

$name= $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($name=="admin" && $password=="admin123"){
     echo "VALID";
     header('Location: http://www.google.com/');exit;
}
else
{
     echo "NOT VALID";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I redirect my output to another page, if it is "VALID"?

Comment: Yes if valid then redirect using header().

Comment: Alright. I dont have enough credits to upvote. I will do so once I have enough credits.

Comment: Check edited code for redirect. You have not credit for UV but you can accept the correct answer by tick true on answer. @RowenaRavenclaw

Comment: Also use trim() with post data to remove whitespace. trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string. Its gud suggestion from @Object Manipulator.

Comment: Missing one opening bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function on your POST data.

```
$name     = trim($_POST['user']);

$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if ($name == "admin" && $password == "admin123") {         

   echo "VALID";

} else {

    echo "NOT VALID";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried code like this

```
$name = "admin";
$password = "admin123";
if($name=="admin"){
     if($password=="admin123")
         echo "VALID";
}
else
     echo "NOT VALID";
```

and it's show me `VALID` it'mean you enterd value is wrong,may be it consume space

> Correct way to do is always check "variable isset" or not

```
<?php

    $name= trim($_POST['user']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if((isset($name) && $name == "admin") && 
       (isset($password ) && $password=="admin123")){
         echo "VALID";
    }else{
         echo "NOT VALID";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with strcmp(string1,string2) function.I thing here problem with